# The Web site address "/sites/T3W-PM/010101140819" is already in use

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I've created a workflow to automate the subsite creation process as much as possible. This has worked perfectly for several day, however. I came in this morning and found that every requested site is returning the following error:

```
The Web site address "/sites/T3W-PM/010101140819" is already in use.
```

It is not possible for the addresses to be in use as the address incorporates a unique project number which is generated at site creation and cannot be repeated.

I have checked the subsites list and the error-ed site do NOT appear to be there. I have also checked the workflow and there is no recursion, that I can identify, which might cause the HTTP call to fire twice.

Comment: check the site collection recycle bin ? probably some sites might be in the recycle bin

Comment: the first thing I did was empty both stages of the recycle bin just in case with no result. It is not possible for the system to create the same project ID twice so this address cannot have been created before now.